# jQuery - triggering a regular function call on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timer, onmousedown

I want a function to be called regularly at a given interval whilst the left mouse button is being held down over a specific element. Is there a simple way of doing this in jQuery or should I use vanilla javascript and setInterval/setTimeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery plugin that provides a `mousehold` event.

http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/

If you go to the **[demo page](http://remysharp.com/demo/pip_ticker.html)** and click on one of the arrows to the right of the last input box you'll see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to avoid more plugins/libs, but if Sime's solution doesn't work out I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var box = $('#box'),
    iv;

function foo() {
    box.append('*');    
}

box.bind('mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hold', e.type === 'mousedown');
});

iv = setInterval(function() {    
    box.hasClass('hold') && foo();
}, 1000);
```

So you bind a handler to both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, and set the `hold` CSS class accordingly. Meanwhile, an independent timer `iv` will inspect whether or not the `hold` class is set, and call your function (`foo`) accordingly.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/7CUFE/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not provide any function watching support as a result, you could use the vanilla setTimeout function as follows:

```
var timer;

function functionToRun() {
    // Function code here...
    functionToRun();
}

var inFunction = function() {
    timer = window.setTimeout(functionToRun, intervalToRunFor);
}

var outFunction = function() { 
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
}

$('selector').hover(function() { inFunction, outFunction }
```

Comment: This example works for hovering, but @Richard wants a solution for holding the left mouse button down.

Comment: as written this code will enter an infinite loop as soon as you hover over the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mouseDown = false;

$('#yourID').bind('click', function() {
    mouseDown = true;
});

$('#yourID').bind('mouseup', function() {
    mouseDown = false;
});

setInterval('checkOut();',5000);

function checkOut() {
   if(mouseDown) alert('mouse is down! Whatup!');
});
```

Comment: This has the checkOut() function being called every 5 secs regardless of whether the event has occured. Need the timer to start on mouse down, and end on mouse up.

Comment: Mistake on my side, I thought you wanted a function to be executed if the mouse is pressed, every 5 seconds.